# Original linked list and its copy, both are getting updated simultaneously when I am making changes only to one?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [19. Remove Nth Node From End of List](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/description/):

> Given the head of a linked list, remove the n<sup>th</sup> node from the end of the list and return its head.

Here is my solution.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:  
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: ListNode, n: int) -> ListNode:
        Length=1
        curr=head
        while curr.next!=None:
            Length=Length+1
            curr=curr.next
        count = 0
        curr=head
        if Length == n:
            return head.next
        while count < Length-n:
            if count == Length-n-1:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
                break
            count = count+1
            curr = curr.next
        return head
```

My question is, when I am making all the changes to **curr** (copy of the original), why are those changes getting reflected in the **head** (original) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `curr` is not a copy of the original (node or list). It is a name you give for a given node that is in the original list. As long as you don't really *create* new nodes (calling `Node(value)`), you cannot be referencing anything else than the nodes in the original list. `curr` references one node after the other in the original list and at a certain point mutates a `next` reference. This happens in the original list. There is no other list at play.

The only time that the caller does not see a change in the original list, is when you don't return `head`, but `head.next`. In that case `head` still refers to the original list, while the returned node reference, is skipping the first node. But both lists have all nodes in common except the node referenced by `head`.