# Two linked lists change simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I know this question has been asked a lot in different settings ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67255045/original-linked-list-and-its-copy-both-are-getting-updated-simultaneously-when) for example) but not always in very simple terms, and I just didn't get the previous answers.

In a very simple setting, here is my issue: I just don't understand why the `dummy_head` is actualized whereas I seemingly don't do any operation on it. Is it a python property, or specific to linked list? Can someone please explain what happens line by line?

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    
        dummy_head = ListNode(0)
        other_list = dummy_head
    
        for i in range(1, 3):
            other_list.next = ListNode(i) 
            other_list = other_list.next
        
        print('dummy_head:', dummy_head)
        print('other_list', other_list)
```

Here is the output I get:

```
dummy_head: ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: None}}}
other_list ListNode{val: 2, next: None}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just don't understand why the `dummy_head` is actualized whereas I seemingly don't do any operation on it.

Actually there *is* an operation on it. In the first iteration of the loop, its `next` attribute is assigned a value. This is a bit hidden, but that first iteration starts with `other_list` being a synonym for `dummy_head`, so the assignment to `next` is mutating `dummy_head`.

> Is it a python property, or specific to linked list?

Neither. It is just an extra node that is created, and its purpose is to *simplify* the rest of the code. Here is what the code would look like without the use of such a dummy:

```
head = None # No dummy node now
other_list = None

for i in range(1, 3):
    if other_list is None:  # We distinguish 
        head = ListNode(i)
        other_list = head
    else:
        other_list.next = ListNode(i) 
        other_list = other_list.next

return head
```

Note also, that it is never the purpose to print `dummy_head` as you did. Almost always, it is `dummy_head.next` that is returned by such a function. There is no interest in the end to the `dummy_head` itself. And that `dummy_head.next` corresponds to what I have called `head` in the alternative script above.

> Can someone please explain what happens line by line?

It may help to visualise it:

Before the loop starts, this state is created -- note that both names reference the same node.

```
 dummy_head
  ↓
┌───────────┐    
│ value: 0  │
│ next: None│
└───────────┘
  ↑ 
 other_list
```

In the first iteration of the loop `i` is 1, and `other_list.next = ListNode(i)` is executed. The first thing that happens is the call `ListNode(i)`. This results in:

```
 dummy_head      (ListNode(i))
  ↓                ↓
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    
│ value: 0  │    │ value: 1  │
│ next: None│    │ next: None│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘
  ↑ 
 other_list
```

The reference to that node is then assigned to `other_list.next`. So we get:

```
 dummy_head      
  ↓                
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    
│ value: 0  │    │ value: 1  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: None│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘
  ↑ 
 other_list
```

The last thing that happens in that first iteration is the assignment `other_list = other_list.next`:

```
 dummy_head      
  ↓                
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    
│ value: 0  │    │ value: 1  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: None│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘
                   ↑ 
                  other_list
```

The next iteration of the loop, with `i` is 2, will go through the same steps and produce this:

```
 dummy_head      
  ↓                
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 0  │    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: None│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
                                    ↑ 
                                   other_list
```

And the final iteration produces:

```
 dummy_head      
  ↓                
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 0  │    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: None│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
                                                     ↑ 
                                                    other_list
```

Usually such a function would end with `return dummy_head.next`, which signifies that the *real* list does not include the dummy node. The caller will then get a reference to this list:

```
┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
│ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
│ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: None│
└───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: This is what one would call a 'clear explanation'. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `other_list = dummy_head`, `other_list` is just a reference to `dummy_head`. It's not a copy. So when you modify `other_list` it also modify `dummy_head`, because they are pointing the same object. You have to copy `dummy_head` or create a new Object. Your problem deals with Mutable and Immutable Objects in Python.
It's a bit complicated to explain so you can read this link to understand this notion.

https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747

Answer (score 0):

The operator `=` is for name-binding.

The statement `dummy_head = ListNode(0)` binds the **name** `dummy_head` to the **value** of the expression `ListNode(0)`. The expression to the right of the `=` operator is **evaluated** before the name-binding. Here, the expression `ListNode(0)` is evaluated to an instance of the class `ListNode`.

The following statement `other_list = dummy_head`, which is another name-binding statement, binds the **name** `other_list` to the **value** of the expression `dummy_head`. Again, before the name-binding, the expression to the right of `=` must be **evaluated**. The expression `dummy_head` is actually a bound name, so it is evaluated to the value bound to the name, which is that `ListNode` instance created before. Hence after this statement, those two names `other_list` and `dummy_head` are both bound to the same value - that instance of `ListNode`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, it is clearer now!